# Pywhatkit instant message to group gets error "'sleep_time' not defined"

Tags: python, whatsapp, nameerror

I have the following code I got from a website that uses Pywhatkit to instantly send a message to a Whatsapp group:

```
import pywhatkit

# syntax: phone number with country code, message
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Test')
```

(Of course the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is correct in my code, just didn't want to leak it)

But for some reason running this returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noam\PycharmProjects\Whatsapp\Whatsappdo.py", line 4, in <module>
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Test')
  File "C:\Users\Noam\PycharmProjects\Whatsapp\venv\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\whats.py", line 128, in sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
NameError: name 'sleep_time' is not defined
```

I don't think there's a problem with the way I'm calling the function, what is the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using an outdated version of the package? [the current github master doesn't have the line that throws the error](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/blob/9d02ec917a803cbe5d8e196c46b760a3ac9db522/pywhatkit/whats.py#L125). In fact, [that line was changed in this commit](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/commit/e76d2e97d78bf785a13bb67771abf793eb6a24b0), so it seems you have and old, bugged, version of the package. You can edit the line in your installed package as a workaround.

Comment: (As a side note, I find it hilarious that in a function named `sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly` the first thing it does is sleep 4 seconds)

Comment: @GPhilo That's so weird, because Pycharm tells me I'm using version 5.3, I even try removing it and installing it again and it still has the same bug! I'll try in VS Code and if that won't help I'll manually change it, thanks!

Comment: It's possible the latest version available on pip is still outdated and they didn't push the "fix" yet.

Comment: Ok thanks! Just changed it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't defined the time it should be like this:

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+919XXXXXXXXX",
                    "Geeks For Geeks!",
                    12, 40, 10, True, 2)
```

12,40 = 12:40PM (it use 24 hour format) This is the time u want to send the msg.